# Historical changes of the drop down list

Tags: apex, soql, opportunity, opportunity-history

I am trying to access the historical values for a drop-down-list custom field.

From the GUI i know that it was changed on a specific date and currently it holds some value.

But when i run a query like follows:

```
Select Id, CreatedById, CreatedDate, Field, NewValue, OldValue, IsDeleted  
    from 
OpportunityFieldHistory 
    where 
OpportunityId = 'xxxxxxxx' and Field = 'xxx__c'
```

It shows the correct `CreatedDate` but the `NewValue` and `OldValue` fields are empty.

Why is that and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Is it a standard field? I wonder if this behavior is generally reproducible. Can you share its configuration to see if it can be reproduced in a dev environment?

Comment: It is a custom field.

Comment: Can you please put a picture of those field values which you can see on UI and not able to see through query

Comment: Can you also confirm that you have FLS on the field in question?

Answer (score 0):

By saying it's the drop down list I am assuming that you are talking about the field of data type as picklist. (It's a multi select picklist I guess in your case)

History tracking for multi select picklist fields will only show the dates and not the old and new values this is the standard behavior.

Don't worry there is a work around -

Using workflow or process builder or trigger

You will need to create a custom text field and populate it with a workflow/process builder or even with a trigger with the values selected in the multiselect picklist field as a text string. Then enable this field for field tracking. And it's done :)